# insert arabic into pdf using itex java nullpointerException

Tags: java, exception, itext

i want to insert text arabic in pdf using itext

```
  ColumnText column = new ColumnText(canvas);  
        column.go();
        column.setSimpleColumn(36, 36, 559, 806);                       
        column.setRunDirection(PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL);
        column.addElement(new Paragraph("الاسم العائلي      : ", fontAR));                   
     column.go();
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:
    String str = new String("الاسم العائلي      :".getBytes("ISO-8859-1"),"utf-8");
Then add the string str to your itext paragraph:

```
column.addElement(new Paragraph(str, fontAR));
```

Comment: it's ok with this  column.addText(new Phrase("الاسم العائلي :"),fontAR));

Answer (score 0):

Remove the first `column.go()` because it doesn't make sense:

1. You didn't add any content yet, so there is nothing to render.
2. You didn't define a `Rectangle` yet, so there will be an error because iText doesn't know where to render this nothing.